# Vega Lite: Color scale for bar chart

Tags: colors, bar-chart, scale, vega-lite, ordinal

I have this bar chart in vega lite in my [Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/@reneelempert/quasar-sketch)

But I want to add a color scale to the bars so that the smallest numbers are red and the largest numbers are green and the numbers in between are yellow.

In order to do this -- I was thinking of setting up an ordinal scale with the domain as `[0,5]` since the numbers range from 0 to 5. The range of that scale would be `["red", "yellow", "green"]`. But I'm just not sure how to apply that ordinal color scale to a vega lite chart.  My code is below

[image]

```
barchart = vegalite ({
  "data": {"values": barChartData},
  "height": {"step": 17},
  "title": "Gold",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "program",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "sort": "-x"
    },
    "x": {
      "aggregate": "sum",
      "field": "index",
      "title": "Gold",
      "axis": null
    }
  },
  "layer": [{
    "mark": "bar"
  }, {
    "mark": {
      "type": "text",
      "align": "left",
      "baseline": "middle",
      "dx": 3
    },
    "encoding": {
      "text": {"field": "index", "type": "quantitative"}
    }
  }]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide `color` or `fill` encoding in your bar chart and add your color as `scales` as done below or in [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIaZJ1h2DcyGA7nRiHETOMtXLDypJhUiioBKKigxEiCDGpoANqgNLKqAB5oAAyU6QDMSjjqbGTqSAhoIAAicMJQ7AwQsmoQIAC+ConJcGmomQAsuSD5hcWl6ABKcLJshgCcAIyzAIQtbSBJqRlZAOx5BUUlZQDCDJpsdYYAMjQAZpZIyYaVAW5sV8vt691ZsztD++gAKuoYhdrnA3qsOl0epQAEzfAa7YZlf5OKZ3XxIQwACSiV0MAFkJuC1p0NukAGw-PYjEBYthOQwAMRshhoEEM-wCmDYU2Z6mJkI22WmVKR6AO8ACcHUTVa71JqGhmxhor+IAAQizxtAYgKPpkABzwwbUsoAaTgAE9DAAyQwABTgVTBcoh+thYlVNPKQNkAGtsWzuepLXqFbNKNkVQjfjT-mwIDBKAB5MNdTLzL1lcakWRkSz24r+tNoaEGg1Z9AAdTY6j9SBgbGqspWJPTWR6lZA+OtVdBhnRhjNNGULfl7fSnpjpurtcEvhehircCQODkY7dCsyOS7owTK9kDRLqAj0wr07FIAAoqQQ0w2Mprec2KR2aMkJaEHJlMeI9GTZe+jSjQUSGPoCDAVAKDNAAuq0GBwDQZBYGgoAQJgcA4GgsybPBOiYBYZQAOJNj+SgTFAD5JGQqEgKG4QgFcNBVD+6AAfsSiYJaOBgugtbKEkUTBDI6iYGU-BpPBXSgEgZBFHwGFlBADClEoTEsWUbbBPhhHoCR87BEgKRsmgsgMIIgjNPBggftK8SgMgdZlNY-LkbIlECXmtGUYIta0epBnoFpSjQFEvGgEW+bxCA6heMElpVL5TjBPJRIwZx3G8SAwgNDYyzZeQEysWZFlWa6jl+rRXE8WUGEpGJShREhegFVcDUgNYEBVEkWUICOyiEUoyhdNk8EUVRXkMXVYkMQFrGbmkGU1egACODB3PhAQ0KQLRWXBQA):

```js
var yourVlSpec = {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple bar chart with embedded data.",
  "data": {
    "values": [{
        "index": 0.03,
        "program": "Deliciousness"
      },
      {
        "index": 0.43,
        "program": "Reno 911!"
      },
      {
        "index": 0.07,
        "program": "Curious Life and Death of"
      },
      {
        "index": 0.01,
        "program": "True Life"
      },
      {
        "index": 4.21,
        "program": "Two and a Half Men"
      },
      {
        "index": 0.06,
        "program": "How Far is Tattoo Far"
      },
      {
        "index": 0.39,
        "program": "Cheaters"
      },
      {
        "index": 4.72,
        "program": "Bar Rescue"
      },
      {
        "index": 0.81,
        "program": "Key & Peele"
      },
      {
        "index": 0.25,
        "program": "Drunk History"
      },
      {
        "index": 1.32,
        "program": "Tosh.O"
      },
      {
        "index": 0.11,
        "program": "Revenge Prank"
      },
      {
        "index": 4.88,
        "program": "Workaholics"
      },
      {
        "index": 0.04,
        "program": "My Wife and Kids"
      },
      {
        "index": 0.05,
        "program": "World of Weapons"
      },
      {
        "index": 0.03,
        "program": "Roseanne"
      },
      {
        "index": 1.98,
        "program": "Everybody Loves Raymond"
      },
      {
        "index": 1.2,
        "program": "Aerial America"
      }
    ]
  },
  "height": {
    "step": 17
  },
  "title": "Gold",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "program",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "sort": "-x"
    },
    "x": {
      "aggregate": "sum",
      "field": "index",
      "title": "Gold",
      "axis": null
    }
  },
  "layer": [{
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "index",
          "scale": {
            "range": ["red", "yellow", "green"],
            "type": "linear"
          },
          "legend": null
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dx": 3
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "index",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};
vegaEmbed("#vis", yourVlSpec);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/combine/npm/vega@5.20.2,npm/vega-lite@5.0.0,npm/vega-embed@6.17.0"></script>

<body>
  <div id="vis"></div>
</body>
```